# Unserialize model object on AWS SageMaker R Kernel

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serialization, amazon-sagemaker

I have a model object that was serialized using the code (in R):

```
serialize(res[[1]][['modelobj']], NULL, ascii=F)
```

and I stored it on S3 bucket.

However, when I am trying to source model from S3 bucket, I am unable to unserialize the model using:

```
model <- get_object("s3://sagemaker/mwls.model_")
unserialize(model)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Error in unserialize(model): unknown input format
Traceback:

1. unserialize(model)
```

It would help if someone even have suggestions that could work to unserialize the model object using only AWS (ideally storage on S3 and coding on R Kernel)?

Comment: I don't know much about R, but maybe this is what you need? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/aws.s3/versions/0.3.12/topics/s3saveRDS

Comment: I have this library downloaded. I tried using this library, but unserialize doesn't work

Comment: Can you try serializing it, storing it in s3, pulling it down and then deserializing it? Also what is the format of what you are storing in s3? And which SageMaker environment are you trying to deserialize this model on? The Real-time Inference platform?